Compiler error migrating to androidx.lifecycle 2.8.0 library
I am using:
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.7.0'
annotationProcessor 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:2.7.0'

libraries in my Android Java project. If I try to move it to 2.8.0 version, I have a message from compiler:
ViewModelProvider(androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.ViewModelProviderImpl) has private access in 'androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.
UPDATE:
Thanks to @IanHannibalLake, I have replaced deprecated library
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0' with implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-process:2.7.0' and  now I am able to compile the project with 2.7.0 libraries version in the configuration:
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-process:2.7.0'  
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.7.0'
annotationProcessor 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:2.7.0'

But an attempt to compile with 2.8.0 versions give me the same error from the compiler on the string:
SearchListViewModel viewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this, viewModelFactory).get(SearchListViewModel.class);

What change was made in the lifecycle libraries in version 2.7.0 that prevents me from compiling the project with the next version 2.8.0!?
UPDATE 2: I have found a fresh bug ViewModel 2.8.0: constructor has private access in ViewModelProvider with the same question.

Does the error go away when you stop using the long since deprecated lifecycle-extensions dependency? You should not be using that dependency at all.

"the long"? What does it mean?

Something that is 'long since deprecated' means it has been deprecated for 4 and a half years.

@ianhanniballake Yes, I missed the point when this package was deprecated. I replaced it with implementation androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-process:2.8.0, but above mentioned compiler error still persists. I can't figure out what package needs to be added to satisfy all dependencies.

@ianhanniballake After above mentioned replacement I can compile in configuration     annotationProcessor 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:2.7.0'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-process:2.7.0'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.7.0'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.7.0', but not with 2.8.0 :( Compiler error is the same.

@ianhanniballake I have found a fresh bug filed ViewModel 2.8.0: constructor has private access in ViewModelProvider with the same question.

The error is happening because the android-lifecycle library is now a kotlin multiplatform project and the gradle dependency resolution picks the jvm variant instead of the android one.
This only happens to projects which do not apply the kotlin-android gradle plugin!
The problem is the "org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type" variant attribute is not requested and so gradle picks the jvm lifecycle-viewmodel variant.
When you add the kotlin-android plugin the attribute is automatically set to "androidJvm".
For more information about gradle variant attributes see https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/variant_attributes.html
You can debug this with the following command:
gradlew -q app:dependencyInsight --dependency lifecycle-viewmodel --configuration debugAndroidCompileClasspath

This is a bug and should be fixed by Google. Probably by setting the "org.gradle.jvm.environment" variant to "android"
A workaround could look like this but i am not a Gradle expert and there should be a better solution.
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel")
    constraints {
        def platformTypeArgument = Attribute.of("org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type",  String)
        implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.8.1") {
            because "The wrong dependency is picked"
            attributes {
                attribute(platformTypeArgument, "androidJvm")
            }
        }
        implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.8.1") {
            because "The wrong dependency is picked"
            attributes {
                attribute(platformTypeArgument, "androidJvm")
            }
        }
}

UPDATE:
I found the following error for compose https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/328687152 which is basically the same problem.
Just upgrade the Android Gradle Plugin to version 8.4.0 and the problem is solved.

Thanks! Your gradle code works and I can compile now with 2.8.x library version! Can you write your solution to the bug tracker https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/341801011 ?

To fix the issue, update the project to use AGP 8.4.0 or a later version.
When working on an Android project that integrates a Kotlin Multiplatform (KMP) library like Lifecycle 2.8.0 or later, and you're using an older version of the Android Gradle Plugin (AGP) prior to AGP 8.4.0, and the kotlin-android plugin is absent, then Gradle will erroneously resolve the KMP dependencies as JVM desktop (*-desktop) artefacts rather than the intended Android artefact (*-android).
For more details, please refer to the discussions at https://issuetracker.google.com/343735749

for a Java project remove :
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:X.X.X'

it should looks like :
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-jvm:2.8.3'  
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-process:2.8.3'  
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-android:2.8.3'


This answer almost did the trick, the compilation problem gone away but instead tons of 'Duplicate class' errors apperared
